# Remove item by value from another column of a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's presume I have a list of dicts. Each dict contains a key `from` and another key named `to`. Now, I want this: in  the second and following appearances of a `from` key where the value of the  `to` key differs from the value of the first `to` key associated with that `from` key,  that dict should be removed from the list.

Example:

```html
[ {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '67f'},
 {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '21g'} ]
```

would become this:

```html
[ {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '21g'} ]
```

Comment: Edited the post now

Comment: You could loop over your lists and inspect the contents of each dictionary? It's [worth an attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: Edited text to match example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help.

```
list_dict = [ {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'}, {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'}, 
              {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'}, {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '67f'}, 
              {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '21g'}]
not_wanted_to_keys = []
wanted_list_dict = []
for my_dict in list_dict:
    not_wanted_to_keys.append(my_dict['from'])
    if my_dict['to'] not in not_wanted_to_keys:
        wanted_list_dict.append(my_dict)
print(wanted_list_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
data = [ {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': '67f', 'to': 'f9b'},
 {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '67f'},
 {'from': 'f9b', 'to': '21g'} ]

final_data = []

for i in range(len(data)):
  if(i == 0 or data[i]['to'] != data[i-1]['from']):
    final_data.append(data[i])

print(final_data)
```

Loop over the data and check the condition for all items except first one.